# Understanding the subtle difference between the use of map() in 2 functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I recently did a coding challenge which requires you to take a string and capitalize the first letter of each word of the string and return the resulting string.
Here is my solution:

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () { 
  return this.split(" ").map(function(word){
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  }).join(" ");
}
```

I understand the above perfectly, and feel that i am rather fimiliar with the `map()` method.

The below code uses a very similar syntax, the slight difference being the use of `item => item[0]`. What is this syntax and where can I read up on it ?
My understanding is, instead of using 'word' in  my case, it instead uses 'item' as a way to represent each 'mapped' word. But I am not familiar with the syntax of saying `something => something[x]` in JavaScript.

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function() {
  return this.split(' ').map(item => item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1)).join(' ')
};
```

Comment: Google for "es6 arrow syntax"

Comment: @cl3m Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Much appriciated!